# Cache a variable exclusively on a function

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to cache a global variable for a function within a group of functions, without calling that function directly from another?

For example, if I have a group of functions wrapped in a parent function like this:

```
function parentFunction() {
var myVariable;

   someDiv.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   myVariable = e.target;
   });

   anotherDiv.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     // use myVariable without it changing when the above is fired again.
   });

}
```

The global variable is declared at the start, it is given a value in the first function, which carries over to the second for use.

But how can I stop it from continually updating in the second function, if the first function fires again?

Could I add another event-listener inside the second function to check if the first fires again and ensure the variable doesn't change?

Comment: Did you mean `myVariable` = `clickedLink` ?

Comment: oh yeah, sorry, thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

You can set the variable only once in the first function:

```
someDiv.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (!clickedLink) {
        clickedLink = e.target;
    }
});
```

Or, you can apply any logic you want there.  Sometimes, saving state like this in a semi-global for later use in a different event handler is a warning sign that you might have a design issue.  If you explain more about what you're really trying to do, we could offer an opinion on whether there's a better way to solve your design issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I fully understand the question. If you want to have two distinct bindings, you need two variables. Maybe so:

```
function parentFunction() {
    var myVariable, anotherVariable;

    someDiv.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        myVariable = e.target;
        if (!anotherVariable) {
            anotherVariable = e.target;
        }
    });

    anotherDiv.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      // use anotherVariable
    });

}
```

Comment: ahh I see, you just change the variable!